# knockout "submit" interferring with Razor @html.beginform submit

Tags: javascript, forms, razor, knockout.js

I have a form that includes some Knockout code, but the form is being submitted too early.  I have the following

```
  <form data-bind="submit:addItem">
            Add illness: <input type="text" data-bind='value:itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
            <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
        </form>
```

The button is interfering with my Razor form, I assume that because it is of type="submit", so when I click this button unfortunately the form is being submitted, when all I want to use this button for is to call a Knockout function.
So I guess one way to solve the problem is to not use the code above, but I don't know what the alternative would be.  Hopefully I don't need to put type="submit" right there, because I need to save that functionality for when I submit my final form much much later

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form data-bind="submit:addItem.bind($data)">
```

I use the `.bind` in all my click events as it stops the click events being fired on applying of bindings and also allows you to pass extra parameters.